# K-type thermocouple alumel/chromel soldering

Tags: pcb, soldering, thermocouple

I am using a K-type thermocouple for my project. I want to to use a connector which has alumel and chromel pins, but there is a problem there. Is it possible to solder alumel/chromel pins to a PCB?

Comment: You need to go from alumel/chromel to copper at some point. This point needs to be your Cold Junction Compensation point. For various mechanical reasons, it's often easier to get the CJC temperature reading at the connector, this means you can simply use copper connectors and have that as the CJC point, meaning you are only soldering copper.

Answer (score 1):

While having this issue, we developed an elegant solution. If the pins are selectively plated with gold on the end which needs to be soldered, then they can be readily tinned. The process is similar to ENIG plating of printed wire boards. The nickel underplating joins readily with the chromel and alumel; the gold plating protects the nickel from oxidation.